# Highlight column header based on cell value within its column

Tags: excel, header

I searched for this extensively, but haven't found a solution yet. Thanks in advance to those who will answer.

GanttChart:

[image]

I need to automatically highlight the column header if any of the cells under it contains "d". For example, in my screenshot, cells C2, D2, E2, H2, and J2 should be highlighted because their respective columns contain "d".

Thank you.

Comment: Look into conditional formatting

Comment: I did. Couldn't find the correct formula that's why I posted the question here.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Formatting would do this for you, simply use the following formula:

`=COUNTIF(C:C,"d")`

Where it mentions "Applies to" in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager, enter `=$C$3:$R$3` the range for your headers.